# Does anyone hold that all shoes are forbidden on Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, shoes

It's a commonly said statement that only leather shoes are forbidden to be worn on Yom Kippur. However when reading the source from the Gemara it appears that all sandals (which I imagine are the only shoes available at the time) are forbidden to be worn. I understand that the majority of later Rabbis held that it's specific to leather shoes, but does anyone hold that it applies to all shoes? If so, who does and where do they say so?

Sephardic sources appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit in which Gemara gave you this impression?

Comment: Their sandals were probably made of leather, like the ones on my feet right now. 
 "which I imagine are the only shoes available at the time" [they had other shoes too](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.10.3) besides the ones called סנדלים, though I have no idea what they looked like.

Comment: Actually an even better source: they had shoes that, at least, weren't 100% leather https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kilayim.9.7

Comment: @Heshy They sound like things worn in the house to stay warm. But fair point

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3159/crocs-on-yom-kippur

Answer (score 4):

The Beis Yosef Orach Chaim 514 quotes Rav Zerachia Halevi (12 century from Provenvce) who holds all shoes are forbidden (though halacha follows the Rif Rambam and Rosh who only forbid leather shoes):

> דכל מידי דמגין מנעל איקרי אע"פ שאינו מעור וזהו דעת הרז"ה

Comment: My information comes from Artscroll Rishonim who say Provence are the mountains in northern Spain that border France

Comment: There's no need to debate about what is plainly available online https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provence

Comment: The rabbis of Provence are considered sefardic tradition regardless of whether their location being part of France or Spain as one sees from the proximity and liaisons between the chachmei lunel and the Rambam, likewise the Raavad -who is from Provence his Talmidim taught Kabbala to the Ramban see artscroll rishonim for many more examples of rabbis who went back and forth like Rav Yosef Kimche  and Rav Shmuel ibn Tibbon. It is the same reason why the Baalei tosfos are considered Ashkenazi despite most of them being located in Northern Tzorfas.

Comment: The Provencals also corresponded with the French rabbis. So what? Not everything is a perfect binary between Ashkenzi and Sefardi.

Comment: But they are Talmidim of the Spanish Rabbis. why do you think the Smag who comes form provence nearly always follow the Rambam? Also practically speaking our term for sefardi includes rabbis from Provence which is much closer geographically then northern france where the Baalei Tosfos live which was near to Germany and very far from Provence.